# How do I get rid of hundreds of ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn lines from my recorded macro easily?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ide

Consider:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 54
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 55
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 56
Range("BQ1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 55
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 54
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 53
```

During macro recording, I have to scroll. And that creates multiple `ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn`. I have that, all over my code.

I thought about using the "Find & Replace" feature to remove all of the `ScrollColumn` lines, but I have no idea on how I can make it remove every line without having to specify the last number multiple times (60 times, one for each number in 1-60).

Is there a way to make it replace every line by accounting for the 1-60 at the end?

Comment: Search and replace? Might be worth it to copy the code to a good text editor (i.e. one with GREP support) to do this

Comment: Seems to me like it would be easiest to just delete them? Personally, I would use Shift-DownArrow to highlight multiple items then press the DEL key. Why is that so time consuming for you? Another idea would be to just do less scrolling when recording your macro.

Comment: The best way to get of rid of something you don't want, is to avoid that thing being present in the first place. Do you know why you have those lines in your recorded macro? :-)

Comment: @Brax Small correction, I have thousands of these.  My macro is copy-pasting to fill out a printable sheet from a long row of information I copied from a database worksheet, so scrolling is inevitable.

Comment: @Dominique I do, I just wish there was a way to keep the macro recorder from tracking my scrolling.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That was my goal, I wanted to know if it was possible to do so using the Find & Replace tool in VBA.

Comment: This question is discussed in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420699/are-questions-specific-to-excel-vba-considered-on-topic)

Comment: Recorded scrolling will always been single line. Unless there are specific scrolls you wish to retain, it should suffice to simply do the following:

Use the inbuilt find and replace, tick pattern enter _ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn*_ and leave replace blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)
- Paste the code in the editor
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (to find and replace)
- Set the *Search Mode* to *Regular Expression*
- In the search field, enter ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = [0-9]*
- If you want to remove the full line, you can enter ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = [0-9]*$\r\n in the search field
- and in replace field enter nothing.
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: I'll have to see if I can download NP++ on my company PC, but thank you for the solution!  I was able to research how to use the Pattern Recognition to remove the lines, but it didn't remove the line-breaks.  It ended up being a lot easier to clean up with the white space, but your answer is still a better one than mine.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: you can download it as a zip, it does not need installation

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was hoping the dev for NP++ made it portable, and sure enough!  I've been using your solution and it's been going swimmingly, thank you!

Comment: While this works, the other answer shows how to do it inside of the VBA IDE and doesn't require knowledge of regex.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a solution, although [usmanhaq's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821576/how-do-i-get-rid-of-hundreds-of-activewindow-scrollcolumn-lines-from-my-recorded/73824276#73824276) is better if third-party software can be installed.  I'm adding it here for future users who stumble into the same problem I did:

---

In the Replace feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), with *Pattern Recognition* On, have VBA find this line:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = [1-9]?
```

And *replace* it with nothing. Then repeat it without the `?` at the end.

The first iteration will check anything with two digits (between 10-99), and the second iteration with no wildcard (?) will replace anything with one digit (0-9).

Unfortunately, it seems that the Find & Replace feature isn't capable of searching or recognizing line breaks, so this is only able to replace those lines with white space.  That does make it easier to remove, but [usmanhaq's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821576/how-do-i-get-rid-of-hundreds-of-activewindow-scrollcolumn-lines-from-my-recorded/73824276#73824276) would be able to remove them entirely.